# Problems with Anaconda, Spyder and Python 3.3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, anaconda, spyder

I have two problems with this Anaconda distribution: 
Version: 1.0.0 (node-webkit 0.10.1)
Conda Version: 3.7.4
Python Version: 2.7.9.final.0
Platform: linux-64
OS: ubuntu 14.10

1) the launcher cannot launch spyder on python 3.3 even after having create the env (IPython runs well on this env). Also launching spyder from the directory is not good from the Console. Spyder doesn't start

2) in either version 3.3 and 3.4 inside ipython and also spyder (only for the version 3.4 which runs) is not able to import pandas. Should I install in every env manually (pip install pandas)? In the default root (python 2.7) I'm able to import it

Comment: Yes, you need to install pandas manually into every env (`conda install -n envname pandas`).

Comment: Thanks i have made it with success. Thank you